# Questions about business logic layer and data access layer in a project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I would separate the BLL from DAL as a best practice. I interact between BLL and DAL via interface.
Example:

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    void Add(Product myProduct);
    Product Get(string name);
    Product GetById(int id);
}
```

where business object Product is:

```
public class Product
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The BLL class is:

```
public class ProductManager
{
     private readonly IProductRepository productRepository;

     public ProductManager(IProductRepository productRepository)
     {
          this.productRepository = productRepository ?? throw new Exception("message");
     }

    public void AddProduct(Product myProduct)
    {
        try
        {                  
            // Here code validation ecc....

            // Add product to database
            productRepository.Add(myProduct);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception  
        }
    } 

    public Product GetProduct(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            // Here code to validation ecc....

            // Get product from database
            var product = _productRepository.Get(name);

            return product;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception  
        }
    }
     // ecc ecc
}
```

where DAL (i would use Entity Framework) is:

```
public ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    public void Add(Product myProduct)
    {
        using(var dbContext = MyDbContext())
        {
            var dbProduct = new PRODUCTS
            {
                NAME = myProduct.Name,
                PRICE = myProduct.Price
            }

            dbContext.PRODUCT.Add(dbProduct);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    // ecc ecc
}
```

Now I have some questions:
- Is this the correct implementation?
- If I want insert a product but I want to check if a product with the same name is on db, do I first call the Get method or I can insert logic in DAL like:

```
var dbProduct = dbContext.PRODUCTS.FirstOrDefault(p => p.NAME == name);

if(dbProduct == null) .... // insert else throw exception
```

-Is it right to use EntityFramework in this way, or do I lose all the benefits of linq?
Sorry, but i'm very confused.

Thank you.

Comment: This may be better suited to CodeReview.SE

Comment: This is the wrong forum for these kind of questions, but it's looking pretty decent.

Comment: I'm going to argue your premise that a repository on top of EF is a best practice. Lots of debate and to me it would depend on whether you are ever going to swap the database out. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4899#issuecomment-200927141) and [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/11/wither-the-repository/). Service layer yes, repository - not necessarily.

Comment: Sorry if i insert post in a wrong place, where should I post it? thanks anyway

Comment: As to your question on checking for existence, we use [remote client validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx).

Comment: You need to create a Generic Repository, which should be able to handle CRUD for all type of entities. Also, I recommend to inject DbContext to the constructor of the Generic Repository class rather than instantiating it inside Repository.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `.Any()` for clearer meaning.

```
var dbProductExists = dbContext.PRODUCTS.Any(p => p.NAME == name);

if(dbProductExists) .... // insert else throw exception
```

If you want to return the existing record to perhaps edit then go with `.FirstOrDefault()`

No difference in performance I think - both will stop when they find the first occurence.